# Django cache_page checking

Tags: python, django, caching

How can I confirm my Django views are being cached when I use the cache_page decorator like so:

```
@cache_page(60)
def my_view(request):
```

Ideally I would like to output cache hit/miss messages in the console so I can confirm my view is being cached for 60 seconds etc.

Many thanks,
g

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you *could* grab a copy of `django-debug-toolbar` (http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar) and watch the queries: if the page is not being pulled from the cache, `django-debug-toolbar` should display all of the queries required to assemble your page. if the page is pulled from the cache, you won't see the queries.

you could also add logging to the particular cache wrapper that you're using, and then reference the output in `django-debug-toolbar`'s "logging" panel. heres an example of what that would look like: http://gist.github.com/242011

i'd also recommend grabbing a copy of `django-memcache-status` (http://github.com/bartTC/django-memcache-status) and `memcache-top` (http://code.google.com/p/memcache-top/), if you're interested in monitoring memcache usage in detail.

Comment: The gist is down, this why you should paste code here.

Answer (score 3):

You can confirm that your page is cached by looking at the headers in the HTTP response.

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:8000/cached_view/ >/dev/null
[...]
< Cache-Control: max-age=900
< Expires: Tue, 02 Jul 2019 18:36:34 GMT
[...]
```

Both `Cache-Control` and `Expires` mean that there was a cache involved while generating the response.

Comment: same can be verified in browser dev tools under network tab, check for response header.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the cache middleware you are using, you could inspect the `process_request` method of that class and find some line like these (taken from `django/middleware/cache.py`)

```
131  response = cache.get(cache_key, None)
132  if response is None:
133      ...

...      logging.debug("Cache miss")
...
...  else:
...      logging.debug("Cache hit")
```

and log the messages from there. I do admit, it is not a *clean* way to do it.